# Резиновая верстка сносок к картинке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать такие сноски к картинке, при резиновой верстке (картинка фиксирована и выровнена по центру, текстовые блоки изменяют ширину пропорционально изменению ширины страницы). Количество текста в сноске может меняться, и стать, например, в 2 раза больше.

Пример:

[image: Пример]

Спасибо.